# TinyMCE and Javascript conflict

Tags: magento-1.9, wysiwyg, tinymce

TinyMCE is installed in our Magento 1.9.2.4 webshop, but we have some conflict issues with the Javascript merge function in:
Magento back-end --> System --> Configurations --> Advanced --> Developer

When Javascript merge is enabled the website instantly becomes 10% faster but the photouploader in the tiny_mce editor is suddenly unusable.
It returns the following errors when trying:

```
error: error in [unknown object].fireEvent():"
event name: open_browser_callback
error message: MediabroweserUtility is not defined
```

I hope someone can help me with this problem!

Comment: Is it happening on a fresh install? If not, you might want to take a look at the order in which your JS's are merged, because there might be a conflict elsewhere, say between jQuery and Prototype.

Answer (score 0):

You can disable merge js for main  scope and enable it for all other storeviews. If you have a lot of storeviews you must set is yes for every storeview exept main scope.

But i agree that there needs to come a fix for this bug. I had this issue on 1.9.2.4 on a fresh install.